# When / How does ccTouchCancelled gets triggered on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented ccTouchBegan, ccTouchMoved and ccTouchEnded methods which all gets triggered as per the touches are done. But I haven't seen ccTouchCancelled get's triggered. I haven't tested on device whether the ccTouchCancelled is being triggered or not. I am trying to produce the event on the simulator. But it has not occurred till now.

How does ccTouchCancelled method gets triggered on simulator?

```
ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // touch cancelled
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The methods you mention are not standard Cocoa Touch methods. Are you using some third party library? If so you should state that clearly in your subject.

Comment: these methods are provided in cocos2d

Comment: I suggest you edit the subject of your question to attract people who use cocos2d. (I'm not one of those people.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is cancelled by the director, which I think can happen if some other element (like a scroll view beginning to scroll for example) is activated. You can have it execute the same code you do in your touches end method by simply calling the "end" method in the "cancel" method.

Hope this helped.